# R: Split dataset by n

Tags: r

I have a dataset like

```
day | group1 | group2 | group3
1   |   12   |   23   |   23
2   |   23   |   12   |   21
3   |   17   |   19   |    8
4   |   16   |   32   |   32
5   |   10   |   13   |   12
```

I would like to split the dataset into days between `1 - 7`, `8 - 14`, `14 - 20` etc. and run a forecasting method on each of these datasets.

How would I go about splitting the dataset into groups of 7?

Comment: 1:6 is of length 6 while 7:13 is of length 7, so what are the sizes of the groups you need?

Comment: @DavidArenburg sorry typo.

Comment: Isn't the last one should be 15 - 21 ?

Comment: 8 - 14 and 14-20, it's not something rather 8-14 and 15-21 ? (or 15-20 if the maximum number is 20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with a module of 7 combined with `cumsum` in order to create separate groups (assuming `dat` is your data set)

```
split(dat, cumsum(dat$day %% 7 == 1))
```

Or divide by 7 and use `ceiling`

```
split(dat, ceiling(dat$day / 7))
```

Comment: Once I split on the dataset, how am I mean to run methods on the datasets? For example, `splits = split(file, file$id); for (i in 1:10) {data = splits$` i  `;}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Don't use `for`. Use `lapply`. For example, `lapply(splits, function(x) mean(x$group1))`. Btw, what are you doing afterwards? You maybe can skip the `split` part altogether.

Comment: Ok, tried doing this. I have a function called `forecasting` which takes a value x, in this case, the dataset. Using `lapply`, I have tried lapply(1:10, forecasting(splits[x][, c("group1")])). Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Try `lapply(splits, function(x) forecasting(x$group1))`

Comment: Thank you. This works well. Will need to have a more thorough look at `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
id = c(0, df$day) %/% 7
split(df, head(id, -1))
```