# Split R dataframe by n number of factors

Tags: r, split, dataframe

**I have a dataframe that I need to split into smaller dataframes by groups of factors** so that I can paginate tables and figures.

For example, say I wanted to split the `diamonds` dataset into mini dataframes with 2 cut levels per dataframe. That would mean a list of 2 dataframes with 2 levels, 1 one dataframe with 1 level.

```
levels(diamonds$cut)
# "Fair"      "Good"      "Very Good" "Premium"   "Ideal"
```

I'm trying to use `split()` to accomplish this. `split(diamonds, diamonds$cut)` splits the set into dataframes by factor, **but how would you split it up by groups of 2, 3, or n levels?** Something like `split(data,rep(1:round(nrow(data)/10),each=10))` works when each factor only has one row, but im working with a "long" dataframe so the factors are spread out along the length of the dataframe.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729845/r-split-dataset-by-n) question comes close, but uses a numeric variable that I don't have.

Comment: @akrun Won't that split by rows? I'm working with a melted data set (```reshape2::melt```) so the levels of the factor I'm trying to split over are spread over every n rows if there are n levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `split` the `levels` of the 'cut' variable with a grouping variable created with `gl` and then subset the 'diamonds' in each of the `list` element using `%in%`.

```
v1 <- levels(diamonds$cut)
n <- 2
lapply(split(v1, as.numeric(gl(length(v1), n, length(v1)))), 
         function(x) diamonds[diamonds$cut %in% x,])
```

Comment: Nice. Should be noted that the 2 could be replaced with a variable.

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
diamonds$splt <- c("B","A")[diamonds$cut %in% c("Very Good","Premium","Ideal") + 1L]
```

you create a new variable on which you can split the dataset in two with:

```
split(diamonds, diamonds$splt)
```

Answer (score 0):

simple solution:

```
df_splt<-split(diamonds,ceiling(as.numeric(diamonds$cut)/2))
```

Note though there are empty levels in each data.frame.

```
 >table(df_splt[[1]]$cut)

 Fair      Good Very Good   Premium     Ideal 
 1610      4906         0         0         0
```